# Consulta en MySQL para traer registros entre un rango de meses de un año en particular

Tags: mysql, select, datetime

Tengo una consulta en **MySQL** en la que quiero traer todos los registros de un año en particular para luego exportarlo e importarlo localmente. Me hubiese gustado traerlo por el año nada más, pero al ser muchísimos los registros (al querer importarlo no me dejaba por su tamaño) tuve que partirlo en dos partes, en meses (01 a 06 y 07 a 12).

La consulta que hice en la primera mitad del año entre los meses 01 a 06 se hizo bien, el problema fue con la otra mitad (07 a 12). El tipo de dato Fecha es *datetime*. La consulta, que es bien simple, la hice así:

`` select * from `estadistica` where Fecha BETWEEN '2020-07-01' and '2020-12-31' ``

Y en este caso, no se porque, **sólo me trae hasta el día 30 del mes 12** (30/12), o sea me descarta el  día 31/12. Y no es que no hay registros, los hay, porque hice una consulta común y muestra datos del día 31.

También he probado con este otra consulta (poniendo HH:MM:SS):

`select * from estadistica where Fecha BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-31 00:00:00'`

y pasa lo mismo, **sólo me trae hasta el día 30 de diciembre**.

Comment: select * from estadistica where Fecha BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-31 23:59:59'

Comment: Lo que estas solicitando con esta consulta...... select * from estadistica where Fecha BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-31 00:00:00' ...... son los registros entre el inicio del dia 01 de julio 2020 hasta el inicio del dia 31 de diciembre  2020. Cuando lo que necesitas es que te muestre tambien los registros del dia 31. Entonces, tendrías que ser los registros hasta el final del dia 31 , es decir, hasta las  23:59:59. Verifica por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ser la columna `Fecha` de tipo `datetime`, si la hora del registro es distinta del inicio del día, tu consulta no la incluirá en el resultado, porque la fecha límite '2020-12-31' equivale a '2020-12-31 00:00:00' (por lo tanto dicho registro la superaria).

Lo mas simple para no tener que lidear con la hora (ya que en este caso no la utilizas para restringir) es castear la columna `Fecha` a tipo `date` (de esta forma te aseguras de incluir todos los registros con fecha '2020-12-31' independientemente de la hora que tengan):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `estadistica`
WHERE CAST(Fecha AS date) BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-12-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

espero ayudarte si tus columnas son de tipo timestamp, ahi puede estar el error, te sugeriría que solo agregues horas a tu consulta.

```
select * from estadistica where Fecha BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' and '2020-12-31 59:59:00'
```